# how to set background color of the cells which are selected on section tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

how to set background color of the cells which are selected on section tableview

every section or genre should have single selected cell only  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z50VH.png)

**SEE Image description PLZ**

**I know how to select single cell in table view but here I wanted for every section only one select cell**

this my code

```
var sections = [
    Sections(genre: " Animation",
            movies: ["The Lion King", "The Incredibles"],
            expanded: false),
    Sections(genre: " Superhero",
            movies: ["Guardians of the Galaxy", "The Flash", "The Avengers", "The Dark Knight"],
            expanded: false),
    Sections(genre:" Horror",
            movies: ["The Walking Dead", "Insidious", "Conjuring"],
            expanded: false)
]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].movies.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(sections[indexPath.section].expanded){
        return 44
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = ExpandableHeaderView()
    header.customInit(title: sections[section].genre, section: section, delegate: self)
    return header
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "labelCell")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].movies[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

////////////
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "labelCell")!
    cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    //cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "labelCell")!
    cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    //cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}

////////////

func toggleSection(header: ExpandableHeaderView, section: Int) {

    sections[section].expanded = !sections[section].expanded
    tableView.beginUpdates()

    for i in 0 ..< sections[section].movies.count{
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i , section: section)], with: .automatic)

    }
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: So lemme get this clear...u want maybe a blue color for the 1st section....red color for the 2nd section and red color for the 3rd section.....correct?

Comment: no I do not care about the color I just want to choose single movie in genre section like the  image description (See it )

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a complete use of the delegate functions provided by the table view:

Inside ***func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)*** you can check the section and row that has been selected. You will also need to check a constant check on the ***var indexPathsForSelectedRows: [IndexPath]?*** array that this returns.

Now that you have a. the current selection b. the list of seelections,
you can go ahead and delete/add data into your final array as required.

So in your case, inside ***func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)*** you will check if the ***indexPathsForSelectedRows*** has the section+row count already. If it does, then simply play with the highlighting in the ***tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)*** and then change the array that stores the list of selected movies accordingly. If not simply add it.